# How to save data like a profile?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two Viewcontrollers:
the first is `ViewProfile` and the Second is `EditProfile`.

In the first View, there's a button named "edit profile" whitch send to `EditProfile`.

In this VC there are `textfields`, `ImageView`, `date picker` and a `segment control`.

Now, I have to find the algorithm to save all parameters and come back to `ViewProfile`.

I can't use `dismiss()`, because I have set a dismiss controll on bar tab (for cancel edits).
I tried by calling from `ViewProfile` by using global variables, but not worked:

Here's the `ViewProfile` code:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! Profilo
        vc.name = Name
        vc.surname = Surname
        vc.cell = Cell
        vc.email = Email
        vc.birthdate = Birthdate
        vc.avatar = Avatar
        vc.gender = Gender
        }
    perform(#selector(getter: back))  //this is the selector of dismiss func but still no performing
}
```

Ps: I still not linked labels of `ViewProfile` cause I would test if image was called first.

---

**Edit**

I Made a smart Think... I decided to use `navigationController?.popViewController`and it worked, but there's still a Problem. I can't retrive `Avatar` and `Date`, why?

This is `ViewProfile`

```
import UIKit

class Profilo: UIViewController {


    func loadData(){
        //load avatar
        let avatardefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let avatarDefaults = avatardefaults.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as? UIImage {
            photo.image = avatarDefaults
        }
        //load name
        let namedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let nameDefaults = namedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_name") as? String {
            labelName.text = nameDefaults
        //load surname
        let surnamedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let surnameDefaults = surnamedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_surname") as? String {
            labelSurname.text = surnameDefaults
        }
        //load surname
        let celldefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let cellDefaults = celldefaults.object(forKey: "profilo_cell") as? String {
            labelCell.text = cellDefaults
        }
        //load email
        let emaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let emailDefaults = emaildefaults.object(forKey: "profile_email") as? String {
            labelEmail.text = emailDefaults
        }
        //load birth
        let birthdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let birthDefaults = birthdefaults.object(forKey: "profile_birth") as? String {
            labelBirth.text = birthDefaults
        }
        //load sex
        let sexdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let sexDefaults = sexdefaults.object(forKey: "profile_sex") as? String {
            labelSex.text = sexDefaults
            }
      }
    }
}
```

This is `EditProfile`

```
@IBAction func EditPhoto(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self

        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        image.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(image, animated: true)
        {
            //After it's complete
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
 as? UIImage
        {
            Avatar.image = image
        }
        else {
            //Error message
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var datePickerTxt: UITextField!

    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createDatePicker()
    }

    func createDatePicker(){
        //format for picker
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        // toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()

        // bar button item
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        //set bar button item in date menu
        datePickerTxt.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

        // give date at text field
        datePickerTxt.inputView = datePicker


    }
    func donePressed() {

        // format date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        datePickerTxt.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var back: UIBarButtonItem!



    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

        //save avatar
        let Avatar = self.Avatar.image
        let avatardefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        avatardefaults.set(Avatar, forKey: "profile_avatar")
        avatardefaults.synchronize()
        //save name
        let Name = self.Name.text
        let namedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        namedefaults.set(Name, forKey: "profile_name")
        namedefaults.synchronize()
        //save surname
        let surname = Surname.text
        let surnamedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        surnamedefaults.set(surname, forKey: "profile_surname")
        surnamedefaults.synchronize()
        //save cell
        let cell = Cell.text
        let celldefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        celldefaults.set(cell, forKey: "profile_cell")
        celldefaults.synchronize()
        //save email
        let email = Email.text
        let emaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        emaildefaults.set(email, forKey: "profile_email")
        emaildefaults.synchronize()
        //save date
        let date = datePickerTxt.text
        let datadefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        datedefaults.set(date, forKey: "profile_date")
        datedefaults.synchronize()
        //save sex
        let sex = Sex.titleForSegment(at: Sex.selectedSegmentIndex)
        let sexdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        sexdefaults.set(sex, forKey: "profile_sex")
        sexdefaults.synchronize()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you should not have variables that start with a capital letter "Email"
Second you can use a navigation controller so you can easily go back to the VC you came from.

Comment: Use a class (reference type) as model, pass an instance to the edit controller and keep the reference. Change the properties. Due to reference semantics the data persist after returning to the first controller. Alternatively pass a callback closure to the edit controller which is called before the controller is going to be dismissed.

Comment: i can't use navigation controller, because is yet used for main controller of the app

Comment: I found solution, or Half of the solution. See edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it. I just need to put statements conditions for avoid nil and use `NSKeyedArchiver`. With the issue of nil date, it just was a missing constraint... i just deleted all constraints and make them better.

This is what appens at `ViewProfile`

```
func loadData(){
        //load avatar
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") != nil{
        let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as! Data
        let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded)
        self.photo.image = decodedTeams as? UIImage
        } else
        {
            self.photo.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "frame.png")
        }
        //load name
        let namedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if namedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_name") != nil {
        if let nameDefaults = namedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_name") as? String {
            labelName.text = nameDefaults
            }
        }
        else {
            labelName.text = ""
        }
        //load surname
        let surnamedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if surnamedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_surname") != nil {
        if let surnameDefaults = surnamedefaults.object(forKey: "profile_surname") as? String {
            labelSurname.text = surnameDefaults
        }
        }else {
            labelSurname.text = ""
        }
        //load cell
        let celldefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if celldefaults.object(forKey: "profile_cell") != nil {
        if let cellDefaults = celldefaults.object(forKey: "profile_cell") as? String {
            labelCell.text = cellDefaults
        }
        } else {
            labelCell.text = ""
        }
        //load email
        let emaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if emaildefaults.object(forKey: "profile_email") != nil {
        if let emailDefaults = emaildefaults.object(forKey: "profile_email") as? String {
            labelEmail.text = emailDefaults
            }}
        else {
            labelEmail.text = ""
        }
        //load birth
        let birthdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if birthdefaults.object(forKey: "profile_birth") != nil {
        if let birthDefaults = datadefaults.object(forKey: "profile_birth") as? String {
            labelBirth.text = birthDefaults
            }}
        else {
            labelBirth.text = ""
        }
        //load sex
        let sexdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if (sexdefaults.object(forKey: "profile_sex") != nil) {
        if let sexDefaults = sexdefaults.object(forKey: "profile_sex") as? String {
            labelSex.text = sexDefaults
            }}
        else {
            labelSex.text = ""
        }
      }
```

And this is what appens at `EditProfile`

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        //save avatar
        if self.image != nil {
            let imageData = self.image
            let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageData!)
            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "profile_avatar")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        } else
        {
            //Errore
        }

        //save name
        let Name = self.Name.text
        let namedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        namedefaults.set(Name, forKey: "profile_name")
        namedefaults.synchronize()
        //save surname
        let surname = Surname.text
        let surnamedefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        surnamedefaults.set(surname, forKey: "profile_surname")
        surnamedefaults.synchronize()
        //save cell
        let cell = Cell.text
        let celldefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        celldefaults.set(cell, forKey: "profile_cell")
        celldefaults.synchronize()
        //save email
        let email = Email.text
        let emaildefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        emaildefaults.set(email, forKey: "profile_email")
        emaildefaults.synchronize()
        //save birth
        let birth = datePickerTxt.text
        let birthdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        birthdefaults.set(date, forKey: "profile_birth")
        birthdefaults.synchronize()
        //save sex
        let sex = Sex.titleForSegment(at: Sex.selectedSegmentIndex)
        let sexdefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        sexdefaults.set(sex, forKey: "profile_sex")
        sexdefaults.synchronize()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```